# Charge Customer at beginning of trial period on Stripe

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription with a trial period which is easy to do with stripe the problem is that the docs say

> When creating a subscription with a trial period, no payment method is required for the customer. An immediate invoice is still created, but for $0

I want to charge the customer at the beginning of trial period
so for example if a customer subscribe for a 1 month with 7 days trial I want to charge them for 1 month at the beginning of the 37 days
is that possible , I am using .NET

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a single, one-off line item on the initial Subscription creation which Stripe would charge for up-front, alongside starting the initial free trial. Please be aware though that with this approach your customer would be billed again after the initial 7 day trial.